# SignalR error with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a class called Startup

this is the class

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

but it never runs and always give me this error

```
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.
To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or configuration method name in your web.config.
```

I have also tried to add these values in web.config but it still gives me erorr

```
<appSettings>
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="MyApp.Startup, MyApp" />
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Had you checked the versions that you are using for Signal R and other related DLL that must be same.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Startup.cs property whether is content type or compile type. The code which you have given should work fine. Just right click the file in visual studio and check properties for compile or content type. Also let me know if you are getting any compile time error.